# Error: `labels` must be unique for SPSS to R conversion

Tags: r, duplicates, label, spss

I downloaded the following files (DS43 Election Returns for New York, 1885-1906):
https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/ICPSR/studies/1/datadocumentation#

I tried to open it in R:

```
data <- "00001-0042-Data.txt"

data_setup <- "00001-0042-Setup.sps"
data <- asciiSetupReader::read_ascii_setup(
  data = data,
  setup_file = data_setup)
```

But I am getting the following error in R:

```
Error: `labels` must be unique
```

I tried viewing the "Variable labels" list in the SPS file by pasting it in Excel, delimiting it by space, and identifying duplicates that way. So far, I was able to identify five duplicates:

- 858 3 G CONG 0100 VOTE
- 870 3 G CONG 0200 VOTE
- 874 3 G CONG 0100 VOTE
- 878 3 G CONG 0320 VOTE
- 878 3 S CONG 0320 VOTE

I put 1 next to the second instance of the variable (I'll remove it later when I can check the variables are actually the same) but I am still getting "Error: `labels` must be unique" error.

Is there a more efficient way to check for dupliciate labels, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your id column name is but something like `data %>% group_by(id_name) %>% summarise(count = n) %>% arrange(count)` should put all duplicates at the top so you can see them. For example, if you wanted to see which values of `mpg` appeared more than once in `mtcars` you could run:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(mpg) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  arrange(-count)
```